# Cakephp : Find Query issues?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have an issue with using the find query in cakephp.
The problem is as follows : 
I have to two models associated with each other..say MODEL 1 hasmany MODEL2.
Now I want to run a find query through model 1 in such a way that it has to fetch different number of results from Model2 Table as follows :

```
array(
      0 => (       Model1 : {   table contents  }
                   Model2 : { array( 0 =>
                                     1 =>
                                     2 =>
                                     3 =>
                                   ) 
                            }
           )
      1 => (       Model1 : {   table contents  }
                   Model2 : { array( 0 =>
                                     1 =>
                                     2 =>
                                     3 =>
                                     4 =>
                                   ) 
                            }
            )
)
```

and so on. In other words Result of Model2 should vary but Model1 has fixed number of entries. I wanted to know what would be the most efficient ways to obtain the above mentioned result.

Further adding - 
Consider the following table - Student (id, class, marks)
I want the following result:

- There are 100 rows in the table. I want to fetch a total of 11 rows. 
  Condition => class is 'Computer'
- First row should print details of student having id = 15;
- Remaining rows should have any 10 ids ie. id != 15.
- In total I need a total of 11 rows.
- One more constraint is that user having id = 1 can be anywhere in the table.

Comment: When you execute a `find` how does it NOT meet your needs? You need to be more specific regarding what your problem is.

Comment: Do you know how to write the SQL that meets your requirements? A solution to your sample would be something like `SELECT * FROM student WHERE class = 'computer' ORDER BY id=15 DESC LIMIT 11` If this is what you want AND if you are trying to logically equate your Model2 to the student example, then you cannot get a solution using Cakephp `find` method.

Comment: but the id is not fixed, it can vary. id will not always be 15 .i.e. it is changing

Answer (score 0):

This is a relation between two model. Hope it helps you....

Model-1:

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'ProductOptionValue' => array(
        'className' => 'ProductOptionValue',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_option_id',
        'conditions' => array('ProductOptionValue.is_active' => 1)
    )
);
```

Model-2:

```
    var $belongsTo = array(
    'ProductOption' => array(
        'className' => 'ProductOption',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_option_id',
        'fields' => array('id', 'product_option_name')
    )
);
```